# Hide input in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I hide an input when choosing a select option?

I have this code:

```
<select>
   <option name="1st" id="1st"></option>
   <option name="2nd" id="2nd"></option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="textinput" id="textinput">
```

How to hide #textinput when select #2nd?
I want to pass validation (jQuery validator) and can not complete when it is selected #2nd.

Demo: Here is a code for a newsletter:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/demo/themerollered.html

**Update:**

I have this code:

html

```
<form id="form">
    <select>
        <option value="1st" name="1st" id="1st">1st</option>
        <option value="2nd" name="2nd" id="2nd">2nd</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="text" name="textinput" id="textinput"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="textinput2" id="textinput2"/><br/>
</form>
```

Js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        'textinput':{required: true, minlength: 5},
        'textinput2':{required: true, minlength:15}
           },
    messages: {
        textinput:{
            required:"Add...",
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Add min {0} char"),
                },
        descriere_anunt:{
            required:"Add...",
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Add min {0} char")
                }
              }
 });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PjD36/1/

I want hidden only "textinput"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
<select>
<option name="1st" id="1st" value="1st"></option>
<option name="2nd" id="2nd" value="2nd"></option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="textinput" id="textinput">



$('select').change(function(){
 ($(this).val() == '2nd' ? $('input').fadeOut():$('input').fadeIn())
});
```

Comment: Shorthand for if else...@Everton Agner

Comment: I hide all inputs, not only "textinput"

Comment: ya ,its also working for all the input tag in your html not only the one..or if you want to hide only textinput then just replace 'input' to '#textinput'  .  @user3276229

Comment: How add in my jquery code and hide only input with name/id "textinput"?

Answer (score 1):

A more complete solution would be:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
   if($(this).val() == '2nd') { // if select's value if 2nd
      $('input').hide(); // hide input
   }
});
```

Change the HTML to:

```
<option value="1st" name="1st" id="1st"></option>
<option value="2nd" name="2nd" id="2nd"></option>
```

#### Edit:

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/rMxdr/).

Comment: Would also be best to give an ID to the select so you don't have to target ALL selects on the page in the jQuery selector. Even if you only have one select now, not having an ID or at least a class is brittle and could introduce a weird bug down the road.

Comment: @steve.hanson - True, but given the requirements from the OP, this solution works fine.

Comment: @user3276229 - It doesn't look like you added the JS code I suggested. Here's a working fork of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/rMxdr/

Comment: @FillipPeyton Correct. My comment was geared more toward the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('select').val() == '2nd') { // if select's value if 2nd
   $('input').hide(); // hide input
}
```

Just update the HTML to:

```
<option value="1st" name="1st" id="1st"></option>
<option value="2nd" name="2nd" id="2nd"></option>
```

Or if you want to keep the very same HTML, then you can try to capture the click event on the `2nd` option and execute this:

```
$('#2nd').click(function () {
   $('input').hide();
}
```

Note that this won't work if the user selects the value through arrow keys on his Keyboard. Otherwise it would work since he would be clicking the element to select it.